# Trouble using Breeze offline data getting undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, breeze, offlineapps

Am having trouble using offline data with breeze, Most functions work fine while online.

Then an error **undefined is not a function** arise in the function i guess when calling this fuction

```
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
    var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    var take = pageSize * 1;
    app.dataservice.getCustomerPage(skip, take, searchText)
        .then(customersQuerySucceeded);
};
```

Here is the modified **getCustomerPage** function to work offline

```
 function getCustomerPage(skip, take, searchText) {
    var importData = window.localStorage.getItem(stashAll);
         manager2.importEntities(importData);
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("Customers")
        .orderBy("CompanyName")
        .skip(skip).take(take)
        .inlineCount(true);
    if (searchText) {
        query = query.where("CompanyName", "contains", searchText);
    }
return manager2.executeQueryLocally(query);
}
```

And Here is how i declared manager2 for offline usage

```
var manager2 = new breeze.EntityManager();
```

And here is **customersQuerySucceeded** function where i think error arise, i works fine while online on the samples.

```
function customersQuerySucceeded(data) {
    $scope.offlinecustomers = data.results;
    if (data.inlineCount) {
        $scope.totalServerItems = data.inlineCount;
    }
    $scope.$apply();
    app.logger.info("Fetched " + data.results.length + " Offline Customers ");
}
```

Here is how i got data offline on the first place.

```
manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

var query=breeze.EntityQuery
.from("Customers");
manager.executeQuery(query);
var exportData = manager.exportEntities();
window.localStorage.setItem(stashAll, exportData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out **executeQueryLocally** returns an data while **executeQuery** returns a promise,

The error was because i was referring to properties on a promise.

I guess i have to rewrite my code to account that...